# событие в метод - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-7.0

метод как результат должен возвращать данные из события (например формы WinForms)
как упаковать событие в метод?

```
string method(string s)
{
  form.ShowString(s);
  //дождаться события SomeEvent
  return //результат из события
}

partial class MainForm:Form
{
  event Action<string> SomeEvent;//вызывается, например, по нажатию кнопки
  void ShowString(string s)
  {
     //тело метода, провоцирует событие SomeEvent
  }
}
```

Comment: Может, просто вызвать метод из события?

Comment: @test123 не выйдет! событие и есть ответ на вызов этого метода!

Comment: вы на событие подписываетесь, а оно в свою очередь вызывает метод-обработчик этого события, через аргумент унаследованный от `EventArgs` можно передать все, что нужно вам.

Comment: @Bulson я показал пример как оно должно работать. Вы не поняли задачу!

Comment: Событие в принципе ничего не возвражает.  То что вы где-то вызывайте метод другого класса просто вызовет цепчоку вызовов всех методов, которые подписаны на это событие.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В таком случае нужно использовать асинхронность и TaskCompletionSource:

```
async Task<string> method(string s)
{
     var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
     form.SomeEvent += tcs.SetResult; // Повезло что совпали сигнатуры
     try {
         form.ShowString(s);
         return await tcs.Task;
     } finally {
         form.SomeEvent -= tcs.SetResult;
     }
}
```

Иногда можно обойтись без события:

```
async Task<string> ShowString(string s)
{
     Debug.Assert(form.someTCS == null);

     var tcs = form.someTCS = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
     try {
         form.ShowString(s);
         return tcs.Task;
     } finally {
         form.someTCS = null;
     }
}
```

Иногда сигнатуры не совпадают и приходится писать более сложно:

```
async Task<string> ShowString(string s)
{
     var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
     SomeEventHandler handler = (o, e) => tcs.SetResult(e.Result);
     form.SomeEvent += handler;
     try {
         form.ShowString(s);
         return await tcs.Task;
     } finally {
         form.SomeEvent -= handler;
     }
}
```

В любом случае, вам придется "тянуть" асинхронный код сквозь все уровни выше:

```
async Task method2()
{
    var msg = await method("Hello, world!");
    // ...
}
```

*Ну и небольшое замечание по архитектуре: подобный метод который только с формой и работает гораздо лучше смотрится в самом классе формы.*

Comment: спасибо! (очень подробно!) надеялся узнать решение без TCS, но кажется выйдет только велосипед